# Kedro template configuration does not load globals.yml configuration into catalog.yml

Tags: yaml, config, templating, kedro

I am using Kedro to create some data pipelines, for which I have various file formats, as well as a custom one. According to the [documentation](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro_project_setup/configuration.html?highlight=globals), I have created a `globals.yml` under `config/base` where I have created some global variables to reference in the `catalog.yml`. Unfortunately, I can't seem to make it work.

`globals.yml` looks like this:

```
paths:
    base_path: "s3://my_project"

datasets:
    pdf: "base.PDFDataSet"
    png: "pillow.ImageDataSet"
    csv: "pandas.CSVDataSet"
    excel: "pandas.ExcelDataSet"

data_folders:
    raw: "01_raw"
    intermediate: "02_intermediate"
    primary: "03_primary"
    feature: "04_feature"
    model_input: "05_model_input"
    models: "06_models"
    model_output: "07_model_output"
    reporting: "08_reporting"
```

`settings.py` looks like this:

```
from kedro.config import TemplatedConfigLoader
CONFIG_LOADER_CLASS = TemplatedConfigLoader
CONFIG_LOADER_ARGS = {
    "globals_pattern": "*globals.yml",
}
```

`catalog.yml` looks like this:

```
_label_images: &label_images
  type: PartitionedDataSet
  path: "${paths.base_path}/data/${data_folders.raw}/label_images"
  dataset: ${datasets.png}

label_images_png:
  <<: *label_images
  filename_suffix: .png

label_images_jpg:
  <<: *label_images
  filename_suffix: .jpg

label_images_jpeg:
  <<: *label_images
  filename_suffix: .jpeg

label_images_pdf:
  <<: *label_images
  dataset: base.PDFDataSet
  filename_suffix: .pdf

my_project_label_extracts:
  type: PartitionedDataSet
  path: s3://my_project/data/01_raw/label_extracts
  dataset: pandas.ExcelDataSet
```

I believe I should be able to reference the variable inside the `catalog.yml` with the ${...}. However, I get this error:

```
Invalid bucket name "${bucket}": Bucket name must match the regex
"^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex
"^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-
Z0-9\-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA
-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

Comment: Hi @Michael the error is coming from the underlying AWS Client used by fsspec to write to S3. The bucket name you are trying to use is I guess anonymised in your `paths.base_path` attribute. Can you verify there are no issues with that value and it doesn't violate the regular expression the validation error is throwing?

Comment: Hey @datajoely, I can verify that the underlying AWS client works fine, since when the values are hard coded, they work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 0.17.x

Change the return of the function `register_config_loader`  in your `hooks.py`:

`return TemplatedConfigLoader(conf_paths, globals_pattern='*globals.yml', globals_dict={'KEDRO_ENV': env})`

You might also want to `import` as : `from kedro.config import ConfigLoader, TemplatedConfigLoader`

Comment: I'm using Kedro v0.18.2 and I don't have a `hooks.py`. The documentation mentions that uncommenting a few lines from the `settings.py` (the ones in my setting.py) but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Got it , for 18 it is a bit different , 

Could you try uncommenting these lines 

`HOOKS = (ProjectHooks(),) (ln 7 ) `

`CONF_SOURCE = "conf" (ln 25) `


`CONFIG_LOADER_ARGS = {
    "globals_pattern": "*globals.yml",
} (ln 31-33) `

Please note and make sure that your params which you want to share across are stored in a file called `globals.yml` which is in `conf>base`


This worked for me

Comment: It gives an error for `"ProjectHooks"  is not defined`. (I don't have a `hooks.py` file to import). I have the `globals.yml` under `conf/base`.

Comment: I see , could you comment out ln 7 again ? I tested by commenting it and it still works. I checked with the team and hooks.py is now only to be used for customised hooks and not for overall execution. key lines to uncomment are 25 , 31-33

Comment: I have uncommented ln 25, ln 28-32, which would be `CONF_SOURCE` and the import for `TemplatedConfigLoader`, `CONFIG_LOADER_CLASS`, and `CONFIG_LOADER_ARGS`. I still get the error `DataSetError:
Class '${datasets.png}' not found or one of its dependencies has not been
installed..
Failed to instantiate DataSet 'label_images_png' of type
'kedro.io.partitioned_dataset.PartitionedDataSet'.`. However, hard-coding it does work.

Comment: I checked back with the team and they have already been following this issue. This used to be dealt differently with 0.17.x and now have a workaround in 0.18. PFB the issue. 

https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/issues/1527

You will find a working solution here

Answer (score 0):

It's because you wrapped it in a string quote so it is interpreted as a string instead of a variable.

Try removing the quote like this.

```yaml
_label_images: &label_images
  type: PartitionedDataSet
  path: ${paths.base_path}/data/${data_folders.raw}/label_images
  dataset: ${datasets.png}

label_images_png:
  <<: *label_images
  filename_suffix: .png

label_images_jpg:
  <<: *label_images
  filename_suffix: .jpg

label_images_jpeg:
  <<: *label_images
  filename_suffix: .jpeg

label_images_pdf:
  <<: *label_images
  dataset: base.PDFDataSet
  filename_suffix: .pdf

my_project_label_extracts:
  type: PartitionedDataSet
  path: s3://my_project/data/01_raw/label_extracts
  dataset: pandas.ExcelDataSet
```

Comment: I believe this solved the error, thanks! But I still can't use the template config as it spits out this error:  
```
DataSetError:
Class '${datasets.png}' not found or one of its dependencies has not been
installed..
Failed to instantiate DataSet 'label_images_png' of type
'kedro.io.partitioned_dataset.PartitionedDataSet'.
```  
However, it works just fine if I hard code the values inside the `catalog.yml` (same applies to the path, as well)

Comment: @MichaelBahchevanov https://discord.com/invite/akJDeVaxnB If you need further help please ping @noklam in #beginners-need-help channel.  It's probably easier there as some screenshots would be helpful. I tried copying your catalog but I don't get the same output. the `datasets.png` is interpolated correctly.