# Kedro template configuration does not load/parse variables

Tags: python, yaml, config, kedro

A follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081209/kedro-template-configuration-does-not-load-globals-yml-configuration-into-catalo) question. I am using Kedro  v0.18.2. I am trying use the `TemplateConfig` so I have created a `globals.yml` under `conf/base`, which looks like this:

```
paths:
    base_path: s3://my_project

datasets:
    pdf: base.PDFDataSet
    png: pillow.ImageDataSet
    csv: pandas.CSVDataSet
    excel: pandas.ExcelDataSet

data_folders:
    raw: 01_raw
    intermediate: 02_intermediate
    primary: 03_primary
    feature: 04_feature
    model_input: 05_model_input
    models: 06_models
    model_output: 07_model_output
    reporting: 08_reporting
```

I have followed the documentation and I have uncommented some of the `settings.py` as such:

```
"""Project settings. There is no need to edit this file unless you want to change values
from the Kedro defaults. For further information, including these default values, see
https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro_project_setup/settings.html."""

# Instantiated project hooks.
# from certifai.hooks import ProjectHooks
# HOOKS = (ProjectHooks(),)

# Installed plugins for which to disable hook auto-registration.
# DISABLE_HOOKS_FOR_PLUGINS = ("kedro-viz",)

# Class that manages storing KedroSession data.
# from kedro.framework.session.store import ShelveStore
# SESSION_STORE_CLASS = ShelveStore
# Keyword arguments to pass to the `SESSION_STORE_CLASS` constructor.
# SESSION_STORE_ARGS = {
#     "path": "./sessions"
# }

# Class that manages Kedro's library components.
# from kedro.framework.context import KedroContext
# CONTEXT_CLASS = KedroContext

# Directory that holds configuration.
# CONF_SOURCE = "conf"

# Class that manages how configuration is loaded.
from kedro.config import TemplatedConfigLoader
CONFIG_LOADER_CLASS = TemplatedConfigLoader
CONFIG_LOADER_ARGS = {
    "globals_pattern": "*globals.yml",
}

# Class that manages the Data Catalog.
# from kedro.io import DataCatalog
# DATA_CATALOG_CLASS = DataCatalog
```

`catalog.yml` looks like this:

```
_label_images: &label_images
  type: PartitionedDataSet
  path: ${paths.base_path}/data/${data_folders.raw}/label_images
  dataset: ${datasets.png}

label_images_png:
  <<: *label_images
  filename_suffix: .png

label_images_jpg:
  <<: *label_images
  filename_suffix: .jpg

label_images_jpeg:
  <<: *label_images
  filename_suffix: .jpeg

label_images_pdf:
  <<: *label_images
  dataset: base.PDFDataSet
  filename_suffix: .pdf

my_project_label_extracts:
  type: PartitionedDataSet
  path: s3://my_project/data/01_raw/label_extracts
  dataset: pandas.ExcelDataSet
```

My testing script looks like this:

```
from kedro.config import ConfigLoader
from kedro.framework.project import settings
from pathlib import Path
from kedro.extras.datasets import pillow

project_path = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent

conf_path = str(project_path / settings.CONF_SOURCE)
conf_loader = ConfigLoader(conf_source=conf_path, env="base")
conf_catalog = conf_loader.get("catalog*", "catalog*/**")

images_dataset = pillow.ImageDataSet.from_config("label_images_png", conf_catalog["label_images_png"])
images_loader = images_dataset.load()
images_loader["00337180800086"]().show()
```

With hard-coded values inside the `catalog.yml`, the script runs and outputs an image, However, with the template config it does not work. Am I missing something?

P.S. Apologies if the question is duplicated.

Comment: I forgot to mention the different errors I get, apologies:  DataSetError: No partitions found in `'${paths.base_path}/data/${data_folders.raw}/label_images' `And: `DataSetError:
Class '${datasets.png}' not found or one of its dependencies has not been
installed..
Failed to instantiate DataSet 'label_images_png' of type
'kedro.io.partitioned_dataset.PartitionedDataSet'.`

Answer (score 0):

The first bug I've noticed is in your catalog for the entry:

```
_label_images: &label_images
  type: PartitionedDataSet
  path: ${paths.base_path}/data/${data_folders.raw}/label_images
  dataset: ${datasets.png}
```

You've missed the type key for the dataset. The correct entry should be:

```
_label_images: &label_images
  type: PartitionedDataSet
  path: ${paths.base_path}/data/${data_folders.raw}/label_images
  dataset:
    type: ${datasets.png}
```

If you now run the script with the `TemplatedConfigLoader` you should hopefully not receive the mentioned errors anymore:

```
from kedro.config import ConfigLoader, TemplatedConfigLoader
from kedro.framework.project import settings
from pathlib import Path
from kedro.extras.datasets import pillow

project_path = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent

conf_path = str(project_path / settings.CONF_SOURCE)
conf_loader = TemplatedConfigLoader(conf_source=conf_path, env="base", globals_pattern="*globals.yml")
conf_catalog = conf_loader.get("catalog*", "catalog*/**")

images_dataset = pillow.ImageDataSet.from_config("label_images_png", conf_catalog["label_images_png"])
images_loader = images_dataset.load()
images_loader["00337180800086"]().show()
```

For ease of communication you might want to join the Kedro Discord channel so we can respond to you in real time: https://discord.gg/akJDeVaxnB

Comment: That's great! :)